# how securing a public nodejs api to only requests from the frontend

Tags: node.js

I have a node frontend express server and a node api express server.

How can I best ensure that only requests that are made to the api are made from the frontend express server?

There is no user authentication so the user will not be sending a jwt with each request.

Comment: There is no bulletproof way to do this.  It's entirely possible to craft a cURL command that will make it look like my request is coming from whatever front-end you want me to use.  What are you actually trying to prevent?  What do you think restricting access to a front-end will do?

Comment: I can put all the DDOS and WAF stuff on the frontend but if I don't ensure all calls are coming from the frontend then I have to protect both.

Comment: can you configure the firewall of api server to accept only ip address of the frontend express server?

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon I'm actually just checking that.  I think I can.  If I can do that then, do you think that is enough?

Comment: @dagda1 i have posted my opinion in the answer section below because it is quite long sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to set the Content Security Policy using Helmet.js And you can easily add other security features using Helmet.

```
const helmet = require('helmet')

app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    // styleSrc probably not needed but you can set those too
    styleSrc: ["'self'", 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com']
  }
}))
```

> This effectively tells the browser “only load things that are from my own domain”

https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/csp/

https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet

Comment: This won't stop me from making a cURL request to the server.  It will just prevent a browser from letting another front-end make the request.

Comment: as @zero298 mentioned, this only works for browser requests.

Answer (score 2):

in my opinions, you should

1. configure the firewall of api server to accept only ip address of the frontend express server with only port 443 also.
2. please add basic authentication to the header in every APIs, then the front-end must attach some username/password or secret to the header of all APIs calls.
3. in your server APIs, please include your security library, e.g., helmet.js also. it can help you secure your APIs server.